# Configure Logitech MX Master 2s via xbindkeys

Tags: mouse, logitech

So, I've tried almost everything but I'm having a hard time understanding how to create the .xbindkeys file. If someone can help me (already tried xbindkeys-config and it just crashes) to set some specific buttons do a specific job.

I need to map the button 6 (thats the hor scroll up) to Ctrl + Alt + Up and the button 7 to Ctrl + Alt + Down (yeap, I've set it to increase and decrease volume).

Also, I used xev to find the button number of the side keys but I couldn't get a clear result other than this :

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0x21e, subw 0x6800002, time 3268250, (41,50), root:(2822,507),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyVirtual, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0x21e, subw 0x6800002, time 3268562, (41,50), root:(2822,507),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyVirtual, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and that's for both buttons. Now,I want to set them both to go back (ie in Chrome etc).

I've manage to set the thumb button(after all it just sends a Ctrl + Alt + Tab) to do what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think, here is the solution: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1551271#p1551271